# Using concat for a dictionary I get the error: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, concatenation

I have a dictionary with dataframes, that looks like this:

```
dataframes = {'Df_20100101': DataFrame, 'Df_20100102': DataFrame, 'Df_20100103': DataFrame}
```

All dataframes have the same variables (Price, Volume and Date) and the same Index. I want to put all the different dataframes into 1 dataframe. I use the following code:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.concat(v,ignore_index=True) for k,v in dataframes.items()])
```

However, I get an error: `the first argument must be iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"`.

Is it because all the variables have the same Index?

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: `df = pd.concat([v for _,v in dataframes.items()], ignore_index=True)`? I'm not sure why you call `concat` twice

Comment: could you please be more constructive when giving an advise? Why you say it doesnt make any sense? We are here to help. Yes it is, its a dictionary with different dataframes with the same varibles but different observations.

Comment: Because the syntax highlighting on `'Df_20100101': DataFrame` etc suggests that you're storing the generic df constructor in a dict, but that's not what you're actually doing. It's a combination of how it's presented to me and my own reading.

Comment: ok, that was the problem. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries, apologies for the miscommunication :) Did that fix your issue fully?

Comment: yes, super thanks @roganjosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `pd.concat` on individual dataframes in your dictionary (you have nested `pd.concat()` calls). Instead, you just want a list comprehension to gather the dataframes into a single list and call `.concat()` on that:

```
df = pd.concat([v for _, v in dataframes.items()], ignore_index=True)
```

`for k, v` is perfectly valid too, but it's customary to use `_` for values that you're going to throw away, and you don't use the key here.

You could also just use `.values()`:

```
df = pd.concat(dataframes.values(), ignore_index=True)
```